# In my shopfiy, prestige theme, i want when clicking the add to cart button, not to trigger any popup related to the cart drawer?

Tags: ajax, shopify, liquid, cart, checkout

I already identified the "Add to Cart" button element in the theme's code.
I Removed any JavaScript code or event listeners associated with the "Add to Cart" button that trigger the cart drawer popup.
Still, i cant find my way to solve this by my own

Comment: Customize theme -> Theme Settings -> Cart
You can set the cart type to **Message** and it would not open the cart drawer.